# Incorrect acronym language pluralization with babel and glossaries

Tags: glossaries, babel, acronyms, latexmk, plural

I receive the wrong language pluralization of acronyms using `glossaries` together with `babel` and have a hard time tracking down the issue. Here is the minimum failing example code I've deciphered:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\begin{document}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{gui}{GUI}{graphical user interface}
\newacronym{ui}{UI}{user interface}

Singular: \gls{ui}. Plural: \glspl{gui}.

\end{document}
```

Which incorrectly outputs the text with swedish pluralization:

> Singular: user interface (UI). Plural: graphical user interfacear (GUIar).

Chaning the order of the packages fixes the problem, but all examples I've seen loads `babel` before `glossaries` and I'm afraid it might break something else in the process. I found this related issue but it does seem to fix my problem: [Glossaries' acronyms' suffix in effect are not for the last loaded language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475788)

I'm using [LaTeX-Workshop](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop) to build my project with `latexmk` and I'm guessing the issue might be there. Heres the output log if it helps:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 26 Dec. 2019, version: 4.67.
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy"  "/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-swedish/swedish.ldf (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty `Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-307.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tracklang/tracklang.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tracklang/tracklang.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries-english/glossaries-english.ldf) (/Users/andreasnasman/Library/texmf/tex/latex/glossaries-swedish.ldf (/Users/andreasnasman/Library/texmf/tex/latex/glossaries-swedish-utf8.ldf)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty)) (/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.aux) (/Users/andreasnasman/Library/texmf/tex/latex/glossaries-dictionary-Swedish.dict) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on /Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.pdf (1 page, 14735 bytes).
SyncTeX written on /Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'thesis.pdf'
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      '/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.aux'
      'thesis.aux'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy"  "/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.tex"'
------------
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-swedish/swedish.ldf (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty `Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-307.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tracklang/tracklang.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tracklang/tracklang.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries-english/glossaries-english.ldf) (/Users/andreasnasman/Library/texmf/tex/latex/glossaries-swedish.ldf (/Users/andreasnasman/Library/texmf/tex/latex/glossaries-swedish-utf8.ldf)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty)) (/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.aux) (/Users/andreasnasman/Library/texmf/tex/latex/glossaries-dictionary-Swedish.dict) (/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.glsdefs) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on /Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.pdf (1 page, 14735 bytes).
SyncTeX written on /Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'thesis.pdf'
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'thesis.glsdefs'
------------
Run number 3 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy"  "/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.tex"'
------------
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-swedish/swedish.ldf (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty `Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-307.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tracklang/tracklang.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tracklang/tracklang.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries-english/glossaries-english.ldf) (/Users/andreasnasman/Library/texmf/tex/latex/glossaries-swedish.ldf (/Users/andreasnasman/Library/texmf/tex/latex/glossaries-swedish-utf8.ldf)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty)) (/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.aux) (/Users/andreasnasman/Library/texmf/tex/latex/glossaries-dictionary-Swedish.dict) (/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.glsdefs) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on /Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.pdf (1 page, 14735 bytes).
SyncTeX written on /Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/andreasnasman/Desktop/masters-thesis/coppy/thesis.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'thesis.pdf'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
```

Comment: At least you/i get the correct output for your MWE if you switch `swedish` and  `english` as optional arguments for ' babel' . But of course the consequences for the remaining document are not predictable. Another idea, you could specify the pluralization for troublesome entries using the `plural`, `firstplural`, `longplural` etc. keys manually. However, that is only a workaround and not a problem fix.

Comment: Yes, changing the languages work, but I'd like english to be the main language, hence I load it last. Defining separate plurals work, but as you said, that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Try using the notranslate option for glossaries: \usepackage[notranslate]{glossaries} **It is essential to delete the .glsdefs file before recompiling**, otherwise the change in the \usepackage line won't have an effect on the plurals for acronyms that were defined earlier.  That works for me.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! If you want to add it as answer I can mark it! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `notranslate` option for loading the `glossaries` package:

```
\usepackage[notranslate]{glossaries}
```

Then `glossaries` will use its default (English) definitions.
After making the change, **it is essential to delete the .glsdefs 
file before recompiling**, otherwise the change in the `\usepackage` line won't have an effect on the plurals for acronyms that were defined earlier.

I think it would be nice if `glossaries` used the document language when loading its language definitions; it would be more intuitive.  But that's not true in the current version (4.46).

By the way, the OP was concerned that the use of `latexmk` caused the problem.  But that's not the case. `Latexmk` simple invoked `pdflatex` the several times that it decided were necessary.  Exactly the same phenomenon occurs if you compile the document by directly using `pdflatex`.